# UISearchBar crash when start add text second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hello I have a problem with the `UISearchBar`, when I add in the `UISearchBar` text, everything works fine, but after I will select Detail controller and click back and try again add to `UISearchBar` text , press search, application fails. And I see :

> App crashing with exception: -[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8206e99f10

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

  [self getDesignslist:searchString];
  return YES;

 }

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {


    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}


-(void)getDesignslist:(NSString*)string
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"term":string};
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@homedesign/ajax/getsearchtags",SERVER_URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.tableview animated:YES];
         NSError *error = nil;

         NSDictionary *jsonResponce = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
         if([[jsonResponce objectForKey:@"data"]count]>0)
        {
             tagsArray = [NSArray new];
             tagsArray = [[jsonResponce objectForKey:@"data"] allValues];
    }
         [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.tableview animated:YES];

     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.tableview animated:YES];
     }];

}
```

Comment: where is the relevant code where you filtering result based on search text ?

Comment: Somewhere you are messing a `NSArray` object and a `NSString` object. It could interesting to help us find which line exactly causes the issue. Is it `[self getDesignslist:searchString];`?

Comment: added , sory about format Text

Comment: `tagsArray = [NSArray new];`: this is useless. Could you try to find which line exactly is causing the crash? You can use NSLog() or Breakpoint to determine the line.

Comment: I was try, but  Eror isEqualToString , but i have not isEqualToString in my ViewController;

Comment: It can be an "hidden" call. Another public method that call `isEqualToString`. Could you tell if even the code pass correctly in the `success` block of the request? Try to put NSLogs a little everywhere, and find which line was the last NSLog. And so on, until you find the culprit. It could also be in your tableView code (if you use one).